# algorithm - sort most repeated number first (descending order)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, heap

I have a list of numbers, for example:

```
10 4
5 3
7 1
-2 2
```

first line means the number `10` repeats `4` times, the second line means the number `5` repeats thrice and so on. The objective is to sort these numbers, the most repeated first in descending order. I think using Hashmap to record the data and then feeding it to treeset and sort by value would be the most efficient way -> O(n log n), but is there a more efficient way? I've heard this problem is solved with max-heap, but I dont think heap can do better than O(n log n).

Comment: Do you want the element with max occurence count, or you want all numbers arranged in descending order based on count?

Comment: Do you have the numbers already paired, or can you easily pair them? And you want to keep  them paired?

Comment: It's been proven no comparison sort can do better than O(n log n). Now, if you use a non-comparison sort, you might do better. But, you might not.

Comment: Is this correct?  You want to use create a `HashMap`. The key is the number entered, and the value is the number of times it was counted. Each time a number comes in, the count is updated.  After the last number is received, you want to sort the contents of the `HashMap` by value.

Comment: all numbers sorted based on occurence, starting with most repeated to least repeated

Comment: @James yes, that's correct

Comment: @AbhinavMathur all numbers in desc order based on count. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Perhaps there is an efficient way if there is a bound on the number of repetitions. Is it always a fairly small integer `> 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I Replaced my original answer.)

GeekForGeeks has [example code for sorting a `HashMap` by value](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-a-hashmap-according-to-values/).

Since a `HashMap` can't be sorted, and the order of elements in a `LinkedHashMap` can't be changed unless they are removed and re-entered in a different order, the code copies the contents into  a `List`, then sorts the list. The author(s) want to retain the data in a `HashMap`, so the sorted list is then copied to a new `LinkedHashMap`.

For the O/P's purposes, `<Integer, Integer>` would be used where the example has `<String, Integer>`. Also, since the desired order is descending, `o2` and `o1` would be reversed in the `return` statement of the comparator:

```
return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
```

There are mathematical proofs that no comparison sort can run in less than O(n log n).

Comment: I tried to include some links in my answer, but the editor didn't accept them, claiming they were improperly formatted `code` examples.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: _"I'm assuming"_. You can wait for OP to clarify the question then, since you have already raised queries on the question

Comment: @James I'm looking to sort all numbers based on count, descending order, most repeated appears first

Comment: @James right, and there's no way a max heap or any data structure can achieve a better efficiency than n log n, right?

Comment: @kajokiman  If you avoid the need to compare elements being sorted, it is possible to have better efficiency than O(n log n).  Wikipedia has a table of non-comparison sorts, where each entry in the table has a link to an article about that sort. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Non-comparison_sorts

Answer (score 1):

I think with bucket-style sorting, O(N) complexity is possible. At least in theory. But it comes with additional cost in terms of memory for the buckets. That may make the approach intractable in practice.

The buckets are HashSets. Each bucket holds all numbers with the same count. For fast access, we keep the buckets in an ArrayList, each bucket at the index position of its count.

Like the OP, we use a HashMap to associate numbers with counters. When a number arrives, we increment the counter and move the number from the bucket of the old count to the bucket of the new count. That keeps the numbers sorted at all times.

Each arriving number takes O(1) to process, so all take O(N).

Answer (score 1):

You can get a sorted list of `Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>` like this:

```
    List<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> entries = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted((a,b)->a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It should be in O(n*log(n)).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the number is unique,

Why sort? just loop through every key save max occurence, and you’ll get it in O(n)

```py
maxNum = 0
maxValue = -1
loop numbers:
   if (numbers[i].value > maxValue) :
     maxValue = numbers[i].value
     maxNum = numbers[i].key
return maxNum;
```

Comment: I doubt the O/P was seeking the single maximum number.  The way I read it, the O/P wanted to sort pairs of numbers using the 2nd number of a pair.

Comment: I read it literally the OP wrote `the most repeated first`

Comment: And the question header supports your interpretation.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, what is this `question header` the first time I heard it?

Comment: "algorithm - most repeated number" -- Maybe I should have said "Title" instead of "header".  It implies the O/P is looking for a single value

Comment: @owenizedd I just clarified the title, sorry for the confusion. I want all numbers printed starting from the most repeated to the least repeated. in case of ties, print the bigger number first

Comment: `most repeated firt` does not imply a single value, it implies 2nd most repeated 2nd, 3rd most repeated 3rd and least repeated last.